# Unable to cast object on getting remaining days

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am trying to get the remaining date to two decimal points

code I tried

```
(Math.Round((Convert.ToDecimal(DateTime.Now - i.dueDate)),2)).ToString()
```

Error I am getting

> Unable to cast object of type 'System.TimeSpan' to type 'System.IConvertible'.

How can i solve this ?

Comment: Please post an example of sample input/expected output. You could use `(DateTime.Now - i.dueDate).TotalDays` too.

Answer (score 1):

Use this snippet code:

```
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var today = DateTime.Now;
        var sevenDaysAgo = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-7);
        var difference = today - sevenDaysAgo;

        Console.WriteLine(Math.Round(difference.TotalDays, 2, 
              MidpointRounding.ToZero));
    }
```

Output:

[image: Output is 6.99]

Comment: my duedate type public DateTime?  so in different i can not able to get total days

Comment: @user18044289 you can wrap it inside ( ... )

Comment: if i have DateTime.Now - i.dueDate error message i have :- operator '-' can not be applied of type string and DateTime?

Comment: first, apply the - operator, and then cast it to the string

Comment: what is the type of `i.dueDate` ?

Answer (score 0):

Subtracting two dates yields a [`TimeSpan`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.timespan?view=net-6.0) which is not directly convertible to a decimal. What value do you want? The number of decimal days? The number of minutes?  So you need to be explicit by using the properties of a `TimeSpan` (like `TotalDays`):

```
(Math.Round((DateTime.Now - i.dueDate).TotalDays,2)).ToString()
```

Comment: for me .TotalDays not coming  boz of that i did Convert.ToDecimal

Comment: my duedate type public DateTime?

Comment: ".TotalDays not coming" what does that mean? What error do you get?

Comment: if i have DateTime.Now - i.dueDate error message i have :- operator '-' can not be applied  of type string and DateTime?

Comment: Then `dueDate` is a string, not a `DateTime`, because `Now` is certainly a `DateTime`  - you may need to parse `dueDate` to turn it into a `DateTime`

Comment: can you please give  me a example

Comment: A simple example would be `(DateTime.Now - DateTime.Parse(i.dueDate))` but you may want to use [`ParseExact`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.datetime.parseexact?view=net-6.0) if the string is in a consistent date format

Comment: for both i am getting can not convert datetime? to string error

Comment: Your errors are not consistent - the first says it's a string and the second says it's a `DateTime?` (a nullable `DateTime`). For the second error you'd use `(DateTime.Now - i.dueDate.Value)` but it's inconsistent with the string error, which must be coming from somewhere else.